# Need help in write file operations in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Need help in write file operations in Jmeter with below code:

```
a = vars.get("PARAM_1");
b = vars.get("PARAM_2");
f = new FileOutputStream("FILEPATH/filename.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(a +","+ b);
f.close();
```

I am using in bean shell post processer but above code only will able to add 2 variables in the CSV file but I tried and defined more than 2 like

```
a = vars.get("PARAM_1");
b = vars.get("PARAM_2");
c = vars.get("PARAM_3");
d = vars.get("PARAM_4");
e = vars.get("PARAM_5");
f = new FileOutputStream("FILEPATH/filename.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(a +","+ b","+ c","+ d","+ e); 
f.close();
```

With the above code not write with all 5 variables, write with only 2.

And also for me, data writing needs to happen with the 2nd line of the CSV not with the 1st line of the CSV because the 1st line has the headline of the data.

Comment: Your code is unformatted and in a single line. Please post your code as formatted text and properly separated into lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using Groovy for scripting, more information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)
2. You can amend you code to look like:

   ```
    def file = new File('FILEPATH/filename.csv')

    1.upto(5, {
        file << vars.get('PARAM_' + it)
        if (it != 5) {
            file << ','
        }

    })
    file << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```
3. If you run your script with 2 or more users you might face a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so when 2 or more threads will be concurrently writing into the same file it will result in data corruption or loss. So it's better to consider using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) instead
4. In any case make sure that the variables exist and have their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination as if the variable is not there you will have `null` value written to the file